# why is recvfrom() not updating the received message

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, udp, recvfrom

I am using recvfrom inside a while loop that also performs other non related functions, I am using UDP to send either 1 or 0 continuously from a different machine. The message is received ok but when I change the message from 1 to 0 or viceversa from the other computer the message received is not updated in the receiving script and continues to show whatever it was sent first. When I stop the script and run it again it updates.

Comment: What does updating mean?

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: Okay, what does changing the message mean?

Comment: If I was sending a 1 start sending a 0 or the other way around

Comment: Is it possible that you're sending messages faster than you're receiving them, so they pile up in the queue, and you have to receive a bunch before you get to the first 0 message?

Comment: Is there a way to read the message that was sent last ?

Comment: I suppose you could make it nonblocking and then keep reading until there are no more messages to read.